# CSS Text Shadow + Annoying effect on blank space

Tags: firefox, css

I was wondering whether this "effect" is a known problem or it happens only to me:

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9TUVU/3/)

As you can see the blank space looks like a small gray dot. I´d really like to remove that, but after trying multiple things including changing colors, fonts etc., I didnt find any solution.

When there is no space (see `h4` in my example above) there is no "dot".

I also made a picture in case you dont see the "gray dot" in the above example:

[image: Example picture]

Edit: So it seems the problem is related to Firefox on Windows 7 (probably other versions too).

Edit 2: It is most probably a hardware-related problem, because it seems to only happen on computers with an ATI graphic card. I will keep you updated and so long mark BoltClock´s answer.

Comment: Might be a Firefox bug. I can't see anything in Safari, anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have edited the question as it seems to be a Windows Firefox 8 problem (however I didnt have the chance to check it on another OS).

Comment: they don't appear in Firefox on Linux either!

Comment: and the culprit is....windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed on Firefox 8 on Windows 7. Doesn't affect Firefox 8 on my Mac, nor can I reproduce it on earlier versions of Firefox...

Since it isn't appearing on anything but Firefox 8 on Windows, you may wish to report this as a bug. Include a link to your jsFiddle demo, as well as your screenshot.

Start here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi

Comment: Be sure to edit your question with a link to the bug report after you've filed it for future reference.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Firefox 8/Windows 7 on my home computer, which has an Nvidia card. I *can* reproduce it on another computer also with Firefox 8/Windows 7, which has an ATI card. It doesn't happen in Firefox Nightly on the ATI computer.

Comment: Oh, and congratulations on leveling up to moderator.

Comment: @thirtydot: So it's probably a problem with hardware acceleration. And thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @thirtydot: I do have an ATI card too. I was about to file a bug report @ bugzilla. Do you guys think that still makes sense, since we found out its hardware-related?